# force component update without key

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router to load a single component, but the component changes depending on the url. I realized that the component wasn't updating because as far as React could tell, nothing had changed.

`<ComponentThatDoesNotUpdate />`

I could simply pass in a key prop with the url to force it to update, 
`<ComponentThatDoesNotUpdate key={window.location.href}/>`

but I would prefer it if I didn't have to do that. Any ideas?

Basically, I want to force a component to at the very least, rerun componentDidMount. This is for a plugin I'm building, and I don't want people who use the plugin to have to know to put the key information in.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(){
    return boolean
}
```